# PHP Script not returning db rows

Tags: php

```
include("conn.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sggame");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo $id;
    echo 'working?';
}
```

The above code simply doesn't return anything out of the db. The row name is correct and the loop runs, showing that there is something in the database. However the row is just not echoed out at all. This is code i have used a thousand time before and am rather perplexed as to why it has stopped now! Any help, as always, is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

with

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Comment: No problem, this happens to everyone of us someday, I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

did this code give off a notice or warning when you where running it ? I am just curious being that the problem was the semicolon.

Comment: while (condition); is the same as while (condition){}, i.e. a while loop with an empty body.